# Why ArrayList Get only 50 value into Azure Table Storage?

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I am getting products list into `Azure Table Storage` and that product list store in `ArrayList` and display in `Tablelayout`..My problem `ArrayList` get only 50 values.. how to solve this problem. please help me.

---

```
   MobileServiceTable<ProductList> ProductBrand = mClient.getTable("ProductList", ProductList.class);


                        ProductBrand.where().field("enable").eq(val(true)).execute(new TableQueryCallback<ProductList>() {

                            public void onCompleted(List<ProductList> results, int count, Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                                final ArrayList<ProductList> list3 = new ArrayList<ProductList>();
                                for (ProductList item : results) {
                                    list3.add(item);

                                }
                                for(int c=0;c<list3.size();c++)
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Size:"+list3.size()+"Product "+list3.get(c).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  }
                        });
```

Comment: this this really  Azure database cos your code look like Azure Table Storage code ?

Comment: yes.. this is Azure table storage code @sourabhdevpura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Azure Mobile Services` returns 50 records by default you can get around this by firstly adding the EnableQueryAttribute to your public 'GET' method eg

```
[EnableQuery(MaxTop(1000)]
public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can use the `Take` method to request a certain number of products

```
MobileServiceTable<ProductList> ProductBrand =                                            
              mClient.getTable("ProductList", ProductList.class).Take(1000);
```

To avoid any paging on the server use the `IncludeTotalCount` method